# как перенаправлять пользователя на главную страницу после выхода из личного кабинета? react

Tags: reactjs

есть данный код - для logout пользователя, при этом указана ссылка на главную страницу сайта window.location.replace('https://site.com'); при выходе, но почему-то после выхода пользователь попадает на страницу авторизации на несколько секунд, а потом уже на главную страницу. Как убрать этап попадания на страницу авторизации и сразу перенаправлять пользователя на главную страницу после выхода из личного кабинета?

```html
export const withLogout = compose(
  connect(),
  withCookies,
  withStateHandlers(() => ({}), {
    logout: (_, { cookies, dispatch }) => e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const token = cookies.get('auth_token') || '';
      const domain = getDomainForCookie();

      cookies.remove('auth_token', {
        path: '/',
        domain,
      });
      cookies.remove('rgsId', {
        path: '/',
      });

      dispatch(logout(token))
        .then(() => {
          window.location.replace('https://site.com');
        })
        .catch(() => {});
      return null;
    },
  }),
);
```

Comment: Как вариант использовать роутинг - https://blog.logrocket.com/complete-guide-authentication-with-react-router-v6/

Comment: Вот еще статейка на эту тему, уже на русском... https://tokmakov.msk.ru/blog/item/677

Comment: @ksa благодарю за ответ! в роуте стоит to=‘/‘ на данный момент, до этого там был маршрут на страницу авторизации, но проблема не ушла - теперь вместо страницы авторизации сайт как бы зависает и виден только header и footer, а спустя некоторое время срабатывает перенаправление на главную страницу.. в чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: Без нормального тестового примера что-то путевое предположить сложно... Как вариант - компонент просто долго рендерится. Для таких компонентов можно применить "отложенную загрузку" - https://webformyself.com/kak-ispolzovat-react-lazy-i-suspense/